# Combing interface and type in Typescript logic

Tags: typescript

I recently started working with TypeScript. I must say I really appreciate it and it makes total sense to use it to develop and code more robust apps/websites. But there is some confusing part about the **interface** and **type** part. I have this `Array` of blog posts with nested objects like **id, title, website, color etc.** Now I am mapping through the array and assigning the interface Prop to its parent component.

I am now wondering if it's ok to combine interface with type or should it be reversed or only one used?  And how about the naming confession?

```
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

    import Link from 'next/link';
    
    // import { Project } from '@typings/propTypes';
    
    import SectionHeader from '@components/SectionHeader';
    
interface Project {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  website: string;
  color: {
    css: string;
  };
  logo: {
    url: string;
    alt?: string;
  };
}


    const Projects = ({ projectsList }: { projectsList: Project[] }) => (
      <>
        <SectionHeader title="Latest Projects" />
        <div className="card--grid grid grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-4 auto-rows-[100px] sm:auto-rows-[120px] md:auto-rows-[200px]">
          {projectsList.map(({ id, logo, title, website, color }, index) => (
            <motion.div
              key={id}
              className="rounded-md"
              style={{ backgroundColor: `${color.css}` }}
              initial="hidden"
              whileInView="visible"
              viewport={{ once: true }}
              transition={{
                duration: 0.1,
                stiffness: 200,
                delay: index * 0.085,
                type: 'spring'
              }}
              variants={{
                hidden: { opacity: 0, scale: 0.6 },
                visible: { opacity: 1, scale: 1 }
              }}
            >
              <Link href={website}>
                <a
                  target="_blank"
                  className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-full"
                >
                  <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center relative w-full h-full max-w-[64px] md:max-w-[100px] lg:max-w-[120px]">
                    <picture>
                      <source srcSet={logo.url} type="image/webp" />
                      <img
                        className="object-contain w-full h-full"
                        title={title}
                        src={logo.url}
                        alt={logo.alt}
                      />
                    </picture>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </Link>
            </motion.div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </>
    );
    
    export default Projects;
```

it's pretty confusing still that there is minimal difference between **type** and **interface**. What do some experienced developers who use TS think and would you write it down or do it better?

Comment: There is a [chapter in docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces) about this, here is TL;DR: "For the most part, you can choose based on personal preference, and TypeScript will tell you if it needs something to be the other kind of declaration. If you would like a heuristic, use interface until you need to use features from type."

Re names, `ProjectListArray` is a bad name because it implies a list but describes an item. And `ProjectListProps` -- do you really need an object here? `Project[]` will do just fine.

Comment: @alx Could you please explain what you mean with Project[] which part should I change? Thanks in advance. I have updated my code.

Comment: Instead of defining a type, and then using it, you could get away with this: `const ProjectList = ({ projectsList }: { projectsList: Project[] })`, having `ProjectListProps` does not add much value. Also, you could name your property `projects` -- it already implies an array, no need to clarify it with `List` suffix. But that might be just a matter of taste, so, it's up to you to decide.

Comment: Appreciated thanks for the advice.

Comment: @alx Would you mind checking my updated code now?

Comment: Looks good, but here are few other things. Just `export const Projects = ...`, and then `import { Projects } from './projects` -- AFAIK this is preferred as it retains original function name (kind of a taste thing, really, no strong cons and pros). `Project` is defined here, not exported, but you expect it as input -- might be a good idea to move it to separate file and include in both places -- where items are produced and where they are consumed (this file). Though I really hope some React guru will come by and add some advice, I'm actually an Angular guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using interface over type or type over interface or combining both. Types and interfaces are very similar except a few [differences.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces)
It is just a matter of taste. Though I prefer interface over type.

Type aliases and interfaces are very similar, and in many cases you can choose between them freely. Almost all features of an interface are available in type. The key distinction is that a type cannot be re-opened to add new properties vs an interface which is always extendable.

Also, If you looking from performance perspective while intersecting 'types', interfaces are preferable as [noted here.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance#preferring-interfaces-over-intersections)

Comment: I would be writing more on TS, some piece of writing is here: https://dev.to/ritikbanger/advanced-typescript-series-generics-2444